# Erro limpar campo TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-studio

Pessoal utilizo o `TextWacher` no `EditText`, funciona perfeitamente e quando finalizo o cadastro coloco `campo.setText("");` ele não limpa, fechar a aplicação e mostra um erro.

meu classe `TextWatcher`:

```
public class MoneyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final WeakReference<EditText> editTextWeakReference;
    private final Locale locale;

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText editText, Locale locale) {
        this.editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(editText);
        this.locale = locale != null ? locale : Locale.getDefault();
    }

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        this.editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(editText);
        this.locale = Locale.getDefault();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
        if (editText == null) return;
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        BigDecimal parsed = parseToBigDecimal(editable.toString(), locale);
        String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(parsed);

        editText.setText(formatted);
        editText.setSelection(formatted.length());
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    private BigDecimal parseToBigDecimal(String value, Locale locale) {
        String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getSymbol());

        String cleanString = value.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

        return new BigDecimal(cleanString).setScale(
                2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR
        );
    }
}
```

A chamada no edit:

```
txtValorRecarga.addTextChangedListener(new MoneyTextWatcher(txtValorRecarga, mLocale));
```

E como estou limpando em outro método após a conclusão do envio do formulário:

```
txtValorRecarga.setText("");
```

Se alguém puder ajudar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Voce pode tentar isto:

```
editText.removeTextChangedListener(yourTextWatcher);
```

Comment: O editText já é meu edit, e o yourTextWatcher o que seria?

Comment: O yourTextWatcher seria o seu editTextWeakReference